# How to use ngrok with https://localhost:[port]

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web

I'm doing a simple exercises on [Web App Install Banner](https://zinoui.com/blog/web-app-install-banners) on C# / .NET / MVC which requires https. When I try to test it by using ngrok as hosting services, the website loads for a while and then I received a `502` `bad gateway` error.

I normally run my ngrok with this command `ngrok http -host-header="localhost:44315" 44315`.

I'm pretty new to all this programming and web stuffs. So please guide me in the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can configure ngrok to forward to a local HTTPS server by specifying the `https://` scheme.

`ngrok http -host-header="localhost:44315" https://localhost:44315`

Docs here: https://ngrok.com/docs#http-local-https

Comment: ngrok http --host-header="localhost:44315" https://localhost:44315